# How to get the raw response body in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I have a response whose buffer is the text of an exported csv file (columns separated by commas, rows by `\n`s).
In Rails 3, ActionDispatch::Response#response.body returns that text.
But in Rails 4, it strips the `\n`s used to separate the rows.

In Rails 4, is there a way to get the body *including the `\n`s*?

(I know that I can do `@response.body_parts.join(\n)`.  But that works only if I know in advance that the body_parts were separated by `\n`.  I need a more general solution.)

Comment: There is a `raw` method on the `ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper` module but it is supposed to be used for views, if you want to use it on a controller, you may want to include this into your controller like `include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper` and you should be able then to use the `raw` method

Comment: kurenn:  Thanks for the response.  I will check it out later when I have more time.

Comment: That doesn't seem to allow the \n's to be sent.